# Arranging responsive images in fixed position while resizing window

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I been  trying to make a page with four responsive images in it arranged in blocks. 
Like two images on first row and two on second row.

And since responsive i tried to make them shrink while staying at their places. 
But it kinda juggles all around while i try to resize the window.

```css
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <style>
 #image1 {
  position:relative;
  float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left:250px;
 border:1px solid;
    }
  #image2 {
   position:relative;
  float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left:300px;
 border:1px solid;
 padding-bottom:10px;
    }
   #image3 {
   position:relative;
  float: left;
    margin-left:250px;
    padding-top:10px;
 border:1px solid;
    }
  #image4 {
  position:relative;
  float: left;
 padding-top:10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left:300px;
 border:1px solid;

    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Image</h2>
  <p>This text is responsive too</p>
  <img class="img-responsive" src="img.png" id="image1" alt="Chania" width="150" height="150"> 
   <img class="img-responsive" src="img.png" id="image2" alt="Chania" width="150" height="150"> 
   <img class="img-responsive" src="img.png" id="image3" alt="Chania" width="150" height="150"> 
   <img class="img-responsive" src="img.png" id="image4" alt="Chania" width="150" height="150"> 
</div>
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off. I see you are using bootstrap. Make sure you are utilizing the built in grid layout system. Your container won't be used unless you set rows and columns. That will handle most of your responsive behaviour.

Then you need to set two images in a row. 
Not sure why you'd set the images position. Unless you are making the images reach outside the container you really don't need to utilize the positions.

If you do need the position. Then the parent will have the relative property. The child you want to move will be set to absolute. Google mdn position for more info on the properties. Note: if you don't set the position of the child to absolute, then that element will remain in the normal flow and ignore the relative parent.

Something like this might get you headed in the right direction:

```html
<style>
    parent-div {
        position: relative;
    }
    child-image {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    child-text {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 10px;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10; /*set text above image*/
    }
    img {
        width: 100%; /* fill to parent */
    }
</style>

<body class="container-fluid">
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-6 parent-div">
        <p class="child-text">This text is responsive too</p>
        <img class="child-image" href="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 parent-div">
        <img class="child-image" href="" alt="">
    </div>
</div><!-- End of row -->
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-6 parent-div">
        <p>This text is responsive too</p>
        <img class="child-image" href="" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 parent-div">
        <img class="child-image" href="" alt="">
    </div>
</div><!-- End of row -->

</body><!-- End of page -->
```

Comment: why can't we resize the image and position with margin-top/left style tags?

Comment: You can... but if you understand the box model HTML elements use. You realize that margins collapse, positions remove elements from the flow of the page. This can lead to a bunch of other position issues, overlaps, etc.  It might create a ton of problems for you. Use your structure to build the site, use margins and padding to tweak the site.

Comment: Also, responsive behaviour should be handled by the structure, or you'll be writing a ton of media queries to enforce proper placement of elements on different devices. You have bootstrap, and that is exactly what it's for. Responsive Structure.

Comment: I guess I should have answered the question more specifically. If you want those images in a fixed position, then you need to place _all_ the provided code in another parent container with position: fixed; It will then stay in place as you scroll _and_ be responsive. Fixed works differently than relative/absolute. It will always be relative to the body tag. Make sure to set the z-index of that fixed-parent as well so all the children will show above other elements. HTH